# Freebase not working when language property is used

Tags: database, freebase

I want to fetch a information on a movie, but this query is not working if I use language property (which is essential for me). Is there any way to achieve this?

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "name": "terminator",
  "mid": null,
  "language": "en",
  "starring": [{
    "actor": null,
    "mid": null
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Which API are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the obligatory warning - all Freebase APIs are **going away in the near future**, so you shouldn't be writing new code based on them.

Assuming that you are using the MQLread API, there are a few problems with your query:

- There is no movie called just "terminator"  You can either change your query to "The Terminator" or use the word match operator
- There is no property `language` for the type `/film/film` (or `/type/object`)
- the identifier for English is `/lang/en`

This query will do an approximate word match for the default language (English) and show names in all languages:

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "name~=": "terminator",
  "name": {
  },
  "mid": null
}]
```

If you want to change the language for all labels, you can use the `lang` query parameter, e.g.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread/?lang=%2Flang%2Fzh&query=%5B%7B+%22type%22%3A+%22%2Ffilm%2Ffilm%22%2C+%22n1%3Aname%22%3A+%7B+%22value%22%3A+%22The+Terminator%22%2C+%22lang%22%3A+%22%2Flang%2Fen%22+%7D%2C+%22name%22%3A+null%2C+%22mid%22%3A+null+%7D%5D

That switches the language to Chinese, but then overrides it in the query to query in English like this:

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "n1:name": {
    "value": "The Terminator",
    "lang": "/lang/en"
  },
  "name": null,
  "mid": null
}]
```

Comment: Thank you. The query worked. But what you said is scaring me, "all Freebase APIs are going away in the near future".   So what's the alternative?

Comment: It shouldn't be a surprise.  There's a very large warning box on Google's API documentation pages and the Freebase web site.  There isn't a good alternative right now.  For a film application, some combination of IMDB, Wikidata, DBpedia may meet your needs depending on your budget, application, etc.

Comment: Yes, tried to extract from wiki data. Understanding the query structure is becoming too tough for me. The wikidata API documentation is not helping much. Can you help me to form the query to "get the details of All Indian films?" or "get the details of All hindi language films"? Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.
The below query is returning far too less number of indian films compared to that are there in wikipedia,
https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:(TREE[11424][][279])]%20AND%20tree[668][150][17,131]